# Limpar componentes dentro de uma Tab

Tags: java, javafx

Eu tenho um método que limpa meus componentes, porém, ele não consegue limpar os componentes que estiverem dentro de uma `Tab`.

Eu estava tentando aplicar da seguinte forma:

```
if (fieldValue instanceof Tab) {
    for (Tab tab : ((Tab) fieldValue).getTabPane().getTabs()) {
        if (tab instanceof Tab) {
            // ((Tab) fieldValue).getTabPane().getContentBias().getChildrenUnmodifiable().clear();
            ((Tab) fieldValue).getTabPane().getTabs().clear();
         }
     }
```

O que acontece é que eu não conseguido pegar esses componentes, e na minha tentativa, ela acaba removendo todas abas. Alguém tem alguma sugestão, alguma forma de dar um `getComponenets()` ou algo do tipo ?

Detalhe, que o `fieldValue` tem todos os componentes instanciados e do tipo Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você tem que limpar o Container que está atrelado à Tab (Normalmente é um AnchorPane, para os usuários do SceneBuilder).

**Recuperando os componentes:** Para recuperar os nós que existem dentro de um Container se usa o método [getChildren()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--), que irá retornar uma ObservableList de nós (nós = componentes).

**Recuperando o container da tab:** Se você não quiser atribuir ID's a cada `Pane` você pode usar o método [getContent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#getContent--) da sua `Tab` para recuperar o container.

Caso queria limpar todos os nós use `container.getChildren().clear()`, se for apenas um componente específico use `getChildren().remove(Object o)` e suas variantes.

[EDIT - Estava dando um erro pois getContent retorna um Node e o método getChildren é da classe Pane]

No seu caso acredito que fica assim:

```
if (tab instanceof Tab){
    // Modo 1: Todas as tabs tem um AnchorPane como container
    // AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) tab.getContent();

    // Modo 2: Tabs tem Containers diferentes
    Pane pane = (Pane) tab.getContent();
    pane.getChildren().clear();

    // Modo 3: Forma curta do modo 2
    // ((Pane) tab.getContent()).getChildren().clear();
}
```

Testei dessa vez e obtive sucesso. Espero que ajude.

Obs.: No seu laço for o método .getTabs() é executado a cada iteração, não seria melhor guardar isso em um ObservableList ??

Comment: no getChildren() ele diz "cannot resolve method getChildren()"

Comment: Nunca tinha feito dessa forma, realmente não da pra acessar o getChildren() diretamente pelo getContent(). Estou corrigindo a minha resposta.

Comment: Adicionei mais um maneira de resolução e algumas considerações.